# Inserting a new row into a single column table in apache derby with generated id

Tags: sql, insert, derby

I have the following table:

```
create table indices (
id int primary key generated by default as identity
);
```

how do I insert a new row?

I have already tried several things I have found, like:

```
insert into indices values (null);
insert into indices default values;
```

however that didn't work with derby.

Comment: First question pops to mind. *Why?*

Comment: i have another table that references the id this table. it is a work in progress but i war curious how that works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try "insert into indices values (default)"

Answer (score 0):

You need a `column` to `insert` into.  You have `id` which is an `identity`, which means it will already have a value when a new row is inserted.  Add a new `column` and then fill that `column` in your `insert` statement.